# Does the finiteness of quotients over base field transfer to polynomial rings?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field and let $A$ be a commutative $K$-algebra with the property that $A/M$ is a finite extension of $K$ for any maximal ideal $M \subseteq A$.

> Does the same property hold for the $K$-algebra $A[x_1, \dots, x_n]$?

I have a strong feeling the answer is yes, but am having trouble establishing it. This would follow easily if we assume $A$ is finitely generated over $K$, but the example I have in mind (where $A$ is a Tate algebra) does not satisfy that. Thanks for any ideas of a proof or counter-example.

Comment: $A[X]/\mathfrak{m} = F[X]/\,\overline{\mathfrak{m}}$ where $F = A/(\mathfrak{m} \cap A)$ ?

Comment: Sure, but why is $F$ a field? (I assume you're suggesting as much...) Or, why is $M \cap A$ maximal?

Comment: Right, Mohan's counter-example is $A = K[[t]]$ then $F = A$ is not a field while $K[[t]] [x]/(tx-1)$ is a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=K[[t]]$, which satisfies your condition, since it has only one maximal ideal generated by $t$.  Then in $A[x]$, $xt-1$ generates a maximal ideal and the quotient is $K((t))$.